# How to create access token from Java code for calling Github api's

Tags: java, api, authentication, github

I want to retrieve user's list of Github teams using the Github api. But I need to authenticate the user first to call the api. I wanted to authenticate him by access token, can someone please help me on how to create access token from Java code so that I can call the api?